# PyQt5 install in Python gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to try working with PyQt5. Installed it in Jupiter Notebook, but running PyQt5 in Jupiter is anoying: it keeps making the Kernel dead.

Now I want to install PyQt5 in the Python shell. Official site says: pip install PyQt5. But this however gives the SyntaxError.

Typing help('modules') shows pyqt5install in the module list.

I have no idea at all, what is wrong. Does anybody have an idea / solution?
Many thanks, greetings jan

Comment: QT is always a bit optimised for the os. Not sure which one you use but it is always best to have the sdk Libraries installed and available on your console. also when first time working with a lib in python it is best to use a virtual env, did you do that ?

Comment: thanks. no, i don't have a virtual env. thanks!

Comment: @Janneman don't use *Python shell* but CMD/Teminal: `python -m pip install pyqt5`

Comment: Oke thanks, I'm gonna try and will let you know. many thanks.

Comment: Eyllanesc, it worked!! thanks again!!